# What happens if I have JPA and CMP in the same project?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, cmp

It is possible to have `EJB 2.X` and `EJB 3.X` classes in the same project. And they should not be in the same EJB-jar. It means i can have ContainerMansgedPersistency(EJB2.x) and JPA parallely.

Is it a problem? What happens if i use both of them in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Should be ok, there is little in common between the two, so they should not conflict.